# Aligning components of a JScrollPane to the left?

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment, jscrollpane

Currently, I have a JScrollPane nested within a Panel having a BorderLayout. More importantly, within the JScrollPane, I intend to have multiple text areas listed vertically, with a width that does not exceed the JScrollPane's, and as much height as they need (with the scroll pane having only a vertical scroll bar).

My problem is that the text areas appear to be centered in the JScrollPane relative to the largest text area, and they are all one line.

Can anyone tell me, looking at my code, how I can get the text areas to wrap before the right side of the scroll pane, and how they can be left aligned?

```
private JPanel generateStateView(State state) {
        //Create a new panel, and the info label.
        JPanel container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel infoLabel = new JLabel("The state of " + state.getName() + 
                ", with " + state.getElectoralVotes() + " Electoral Votes.");
        container.add(infoLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH); //Put the label on top.
        //Will scroll through polls.
        JScrollPane pollViewer = new JScrollPane();
        //This will be the scroll pane's "viewport".
        JViewport pollViewport = new JViewport();
        //And finally, this will actually hold the individual polls.
        JPanel pollPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(
                state.getPolls().size(), 1));
        pollPanel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        //Iteratively add the polls to the container
        for (Poll poll : state.getPolls()) {
            //Holds individual polls
            Box pollBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            //Create the poll's panel and add it to the poll container.
            pollBox.add(generatePollPanel(poll));
            pollBox.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue()); //Fill to the right
            pollBox.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            pollPanel.add(pollBox); //Put the box into the pollPanel.
        }
        //Put the panel into the viewport.
        pollViewport.add(pollPanel);
        //Put the viewport "into" the scroll pane
        pollViewer.setViewport(pollViewport);
        //Put the pane into the state view.
        container.add(pollViewer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return container; //And give back the container.
    }

    /**
     * Method: generatePollPanel
     * Purpose: Generates a panel containing information on a particular poll.
     * @param poll The poll to have information generated from.
     * @return The JPanel.
     */
    private JPanel generatePollPanel(Poll poll) {
        //Create a new panel, then a text area to fill with the info.
        JPanel pollPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextArea pollInfo = new JTextArea("Conducted by " + poll.getAgency() + 
                " on day " + poll.getDate() + " for " + poll.getNumDays() + 
                " days, " + poll.getPercentVoteDem() +
                "% voted Democrat, and " + poll.getPercentVoteRep() +
                "% voted Republican.");
        pollInfo.setEditable(false); //We don't want the user editing this.
        pollPanel.add(pollInfo); //Throw the area in, and return the panel.
        pollPanel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        return pollPanel;
    }

    /**
     * Method: valueChanged
     * Purpose: Handle the event of a different list item being selected.
     * @param event The object containing information about this event.
     */
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        //Instantiating JList with a type of ? seems to solve the issue of
        //eclipse complaining about an unchecked cast (originally to
        //JList<String>, so I should be able to cast child values directly
        //to string later on anyways.
        JList<?> stateList = (JList<?>) event.getSource();
        //Account for keyboard and mouse actions
        if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            State chosenState; //Keep track of the picked state.
            try {
                //Try to get the currently selected state
                chosenState = db.findState((String) stateList.getSelectedValue());
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException exception) {
                //Somehow the picked state was not found, notify the user.
                reportError("The selected state is not available.");
                return;
            }
            //Find the container for the gui window.
            Container container = getContentPane();
            //Remove the empty state view container by generating a new one.
            container.remove(currentStateView);
            //Generate the state view and add that to the container.
            currentStateView = generateStateView(chosenState);
            container.add(currentStateView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            //Redraw everything.
            revalidate();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think `Box` is suppose to be used with anything other then the `BoxLayout` (I could be wrong, but that's how I read it)

Personally, I'd either use either `GridBagLayout` or [`VerticalLayout`](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/VerticalLayout.html) from SwingLabs.

In order to facilitate the horizontal restrictions, you will also want to take a look at the [Scrollable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface, in particular [`getScrollableTracksViewportWidth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html#getScrollableTracksViewportWidth%28%29)

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand where I should be making these modifications - for instance, should I modify the JPanel pollPanel in the method generateStateView to use GridBagLayout?

Comment: First, I'd create a new class that extends from `JPanel` that implements the `Scrollable` interface.  I'd have the `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth` return `true`, everything else you're going to have to play around with to in order to get what you want, but this will get you started. I would set the this panels layout to use something like `GridBagLayout` (or `VerticalLayout`) and add the text components to it.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a severe case of *lost-in-nesting* :-)

While it nesting can be a means to achieve layout requirements, it can be hard to find out what exactly goes wrong if it doesn't give the intended output. Also, there are general warning signals that something is basically wrong with the nesting

- deep levels of containers with wildly varying managers
- containers with only a single child

In your case, all except the top-level borderlayout have a single "netto" (that is, not intended to hack around a layout issue) child, with levels:

```
BorderLayout (the state view)
   GridLayout (the panel that's the scrollPane's view)
      BoxLayout (the panel that contains a single pollBox)
         FlowLayout (the panel that contains the textArea)
```

The experienced problems:

- text areas are single-line without ever wrapping
- text areas are centered

are both due to the characteristics of the LayoutManagers, either partly (first) or completely (second):

- The part that's not due the manager is that a textArea doesn't wrap by default, you have to explicitly configure it to do so. The part that's due to the manager (== FlowLayout) is that it *always* lays out its children according to their prefSize, nothing else. That boils down to have a fixed child size, no matter how much space is available for the parent. So even if the textArea were configured to wrap, it would stick to that initial size, no matter how wide its parent can get.
- The inner FlowLayout aligns its children ... centered. So whatever alignment you set on the level of the BoxLayout doesn't have any effect. As doesn't the glue: it only takes *all* the excess space if the other child/ren have a maximum size in that dimension (which a panel with FlowLayout does not have, simply because it's that simple LayoutManager doesn't have the notion of max, only managers of type LayoutManager2 have)

Time to take a step back and review the inital requirement:

> multiple text areas listed vertically, with a width that does not
>   exceed the JScrollPane's, and as much height as they need

The zeroth order solution is to

- configure the textArea as needed
- throw out all layout nesting (inside the scrollPane)

In code:

```
JComponent overview = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
overview.add(new JLabel("All polls for state XY"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

JComponent pollPanel = new JPanel(); 
pollPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pollPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pollPanel.add(generatePollTextArea(i)); //Put the box into the pollPanel.
}
pollPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
JScrollPane pollViewer = new JScrollPane(pollPanel);
overview.add(pollViewer);
showInFrame(overview, "layout text only");

protected JComponent generatePollTextArea(int i) {
    String agency = "agency ";
    // simulates different size text
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        agency += i;
    }
    String text = "Conducted by " + agency + 
            " on day " + "today" + " for " + 20 + 
            " days, " + 99 +
            "% voted Democrat, and " + 0.2 +
            "% voted Republican.";
    JTextArea pollInfo = new JTextArea(text); 
    // give it some reasonable initial width
    // in terms of content
    pollInfo.setColumns(20);
    pollInfo.setLineWrap(true);
    pollInfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    pollInfo.setEditable(false); //We don't want the user editing this.
    return pollInfo;
}
```

"Das Wort zum Dienstag": nesting layouts isn't a means of avoiding to learn the characteristics of the LayoutManagers used on the individual levels of the nested layout.

Comment: +1 for `Das Wort zum Dienstag`, then every day would be `THU`,

Comment: Thank you for that amazing answer. I'm afraid to say that I picked up the habit of nesting layouts from a forum somewhere on the internet, because I wasn't able to get a label to center properly. Not the "best" solution, it seems. I would like to mark your answer as "the" answer, although I would feel kind of bad taking away the answer status from MadProgrammer...

Comment: @TGP1994 no problem, he would survive it <grin> Seriously, his answer is correct as well, we did answer on different levels, so I don't really care getting the check or not, simply vote up to let future readers see different aspects :-)